# Lambda expression for supplier to generate IntStream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How do I replace the `Supplier` code here with lambda expression

```
IntStream inStream = Stream.generate(new Supplier<Integer>() {
    int x= 1;
    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return x++ ;
    }
}).limit(10).mapToInt(t -> t.intValue());
inStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output of above piece of code is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this if you're bound to use [`Stream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)) specifically :

```
IntStream inStream = Stream.generate(new AtomicInteger(1)::getAndIncrement)
        .limit(10)
        .mapToInt(t -> t);
inStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

***Edit***: Using [`IntStream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate(java.util.function.IntSupplier)), you can perform it as

```
IntStream.generate(new AtomicInteger(1)::getAndIncrement).limit(10);
```

***Note***: A better solution in terms of the API design would definitely be to make use of [`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) for such a use case.

Comment: @secretsuperstar Ya I overlooked the `x` being treated as atomic there. Updated now.

Comment: I like the `new AtomicInteger(1)::getAndIncrement` method reference - too way comfortable :)

Comment: Using `IntStream.generate(new AtomicInteger(1)::getAndIncrement) .limit(10)` in the first place, makes the `.mapToInt(t -> t)` unboxing step obsolete.

Comment: @Holger nice point, but I've used `Stream.generate`  as posted in the question. I believe that would require me to `map` it as a must.

Comment: I don’t see why you have to use `map` here. The OP showed code producing an `IntStream` eventually, hence, it’s worth pointing out that creating a `Stream<Integer>` first, just to invoke `.mapToInt(t -> t)` afterwards, is more complicated *and* less efficient than the straight-forward approach. If you truly needed a `Stream<Integer>`, using `IntStream.generate(new AtomicInteger(1)::getAndIncrement) .limit(10) .boxed()` still would be simpler than using `map`.

Answer (score 8):

The [`Stream::generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) is not suitable for this issue. According to the documentation:

> This is suitable for generating constant streams, streams of random elements, etc.

- You might want to use rather [`IntStream::range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-):

  ```
  IntStream intStream = IntStream.range(1, 11);
  intStream.forEach(System.out::println);
  ```
- Another solution might be using the [`IntStream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) where you can control the increment comfortably using the [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html):

  ```
  IntStream intStream = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i+1).limit(10);
  intStream.forEach(System.out::println);
  ```
- As said, the `Stream::generate` is suitable for the constant streams or random elements. The random element might be obtained using the class `Random` so here you might want to get an increment using `AtomicInteger`:

  ```
  AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);
  IntStream intStream = Stream.generate(atomicInteger::getAndIncrement).limit(10);
  intStream.forEach(System.out::println);
  ```

Comment: Thanks @nikolas. The  `IntStream.range(1, 11)` is simple and elegant. I thought I will do it using lambda too.

Comment: You might use `Stream.generate(() -> atomicInteger.getAndAdd(2)) .limit(10).mapToInt(Integer::intValue);` for the odd numbers.

Comment: @Nikolas that's why I would prefer suggesting `Stream.iterate` rather.

Comment: @nullpointer: I have added the solution with `Stream.iterate` which seems to be the best. However, there are plenty of ways and it depends on the use case :)

Comment: Oh, ya I missed it. Don't mutate variables within the stream, `i -> ++i`  to `i -> i+1` would better.

Comment: might just be me but I feel `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10);` is more intuitive for this task instead of `IntStream.range(1, 11);`. the `range` function would be the ideal one in the case of generating array/list indices etc. but anyway matter of choice I guess.

Comment: @Aomine: Those two methods are both a matter of choice since the integer definition. I prefer `IntStream::range` since it's shorter itself and I am aware of the classical `for (int i=1; i<11; i++)` which iterates from `1` to `10` inclusive while `11` being used. :) Right, a matter of choice.

Comment: @Nikolas fair enough, that's why I mentioned "might be just me...". I guess we're agreed on this one then.. "a matter of choice" ;-).

Comment: Might be more natural to write `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)` here. And, by the way, using `IntStream.generate(new AtomicInteger(1)::getAndIncrement) .limit(10)` in the first place, makes the `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` unboxing step obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use this

```
IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)
 .limit(10)
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Ya, I would ideally prefer this over `generate` and then the Java9 version of `iterate`. (+1)

Comment: Use IntStream.iterate instead of Stream.iterate for efficiency.