# Method reference with a full constructor call as a lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I have encountered a short time ago with a [competitive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572122/3764965) better than mine that uses a quite new method reference to me as replacement of lambda.

```
Stream.generate(new AtomicInteger(1)::getAndIncrement)...
```

I looked the Oracle specifications about the [Method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and there are defined 4 types:

- Reference to a static method `ContainingClass::staticMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of a particular object   `containingObject::instanceMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type  `ContainingType::methodName`
- Reference to a constructor `ClassName::new`

I struggle with categorizing this one. I haven't found any question on SO or anything relevant explained in the docs. How would be this translated to an anonymous class?

My suspicion is:

```
IntStream.generate(new IntSupplier() {

    AtomicInteger atom = new AtomicInteger(1);

    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        return atom.getAndIncrement();
    }
})....
```

... I don't understand how is this possible. At first sight, I would guess the expression is:

```
IntStream.generate(new IntSupplier() {

    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        return new AtomicInteger(1).getAndIncrement();
    }
})....
```

... yet this is nothing else than `() -> new AtomicInteger(1).getAndIncrement()`.

Where is this kind of expression defined and how it exactly would be rewritten in the lambda/anonymous class?

Comment: for better references you can look into the language specs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well `new AtomicInteger(1)` returns an instance, so it's the second one. The exact details of how this is translated are implementation specific, but it's a single instance created and this is back-ed up by the [JLS 15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3)

> First, if the method reference expression begins with an ExpressionName or a Primary, this subexpression is evaluated

In plain english, the part before `::` is evaluated *when it's declaration is first encountered*.

Your assumption how this is translated is almost correct, it's like generating an instance outside of the function itself and using that - since it is effectively final, this is permitted.

Comment: Yup, that's where I would lookup always as a source of truth. :) Would be good to include *At run time, evaluation of a method reference expression is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object. Evaluation of a method reference expression is distinct from invocation of the method itself.* to help to understand the above quote.

Comment: *when it's declaration is first encountered* - that's it, now I got it. Thanks :)

Comment: “when it's declaration is first encountered” is misleading, as it will be evaluated *every time*, the expression `expression::name` is encountered. But it must be emphasized that the evaluation of the generated function instance will not encounter it. Which is different to a lambda expression, which will evaluate the expression to the right of the `->` each time the function is evaluated.

Comment: @Holger makes sense, the verbiage is awful indeed, thank you for the comment

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
Stream.generate(new AtomicInteger(1)::getAndIncrement)...
```

with

```
AtomicInteger containingObject = new AtomicInteger(1);
Stream.generate(containingObject::getAndIncrement)...
```

i.e. this method reference falls into the second category of method references - `Reference to an instance method of a particular object`.

You should note that the `AtomicInteger` instance creation is not part of the implementation of the `IntSupplier`. The Java 7 equivalent would be:

```
AtomicInteger aint = new AtomicInteger(1);
IntStream.generate(new IntSupplier() {

    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        return aint.getAndIncrement();
    }
})...
```

.

Comment: I am aware of that and this was my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572160/3764965) :) I just don't understand how is this possible. The 2nd category according to your explanation sounds reasonable. Have my +1, yet I wait for a bit more details.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply the second type: a reference to a method of a specific object, there's no additional logic behind the curtain.